# SYSBASE CONNECTIONSTRING

Tags: vb6, sap-ase

I  want to connect Sybase 12.5 using vb 6.0, then what should be provider i can use to connect the Sybase 12.5.

Answer (score 1):

I 'm not familiar with Sybase. I would, however, suggest the following site:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive